# Case seems to not evaluate all options as expected

Tags: zsh

I'm converting a script to utilize arguments, but it seems that my **case** statement is not evaluating all of the options I've provided. Below is the argument that I coded which is not working:

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

...

```
############################################################
# Delete Screenshots                                       #
############################################################
Delete()
{
   echo "\n*** DELETING SCREENSHOTS FROM ~/Pictures/Screenshots ***\n"
   rm  ~/Pictures/Screenshots/*.png
   echo "Done!"
}
```

...

```
############################################################
############################################################
# Main program                                             #
############################################################
############################################################

while getopts ":chapd:" option; do
   case $option in
      c) # Create Directories
         CreateDir
         exit;; 
      h) # Display Help
         Help
         exit;;
      a) # Archive
         Archive
         exit;;
      p) # Purge Archive
         pArchive
         exit;;
      d) # Delete Screenshots
         Delete
         exit;;
     \?) # Invalid option
         echo "ERROR: Invalid option!"
         exit;;
   esac
done
```

When testing, all options appear to work (c,h,a,p) with the exception of **d**.
Can anyone help me understand why all of the options work except **d**? Is there a limitation of case that I'm not aware of? I tried searching for this answer, but I could not find something similar.
I run the program like this:
`hsshots -d`. This option *only* fails without any error. I tried adding an `echo "DEBUG"` just to see if there would be any output. I've even deleted the `rm` command to see if only the `echo` would prompt, but it does not. It seems to me that `case` is just ignoring this last option.... OR `getopts` is somehow ignoring this option as an option; I'm not sure.

Edited for simplicity as requested.

Comment: How are you using `-d`? Did you provide the argument that your optstring defines it to take? (Every option that is followed by `:` has a *required* argument..)

Comment: I changed the tag, as your script is clearly for `zsh`, not `bash`

Comment: Thanks, I tried to set that tag, but it said it was a "new tag" and I couldn't add it due to rep...

Comment: consider reducing this question to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in particular, we don't need to see 80 lines of function definitions (especially don't need to see dozens of `echo` calls); what we do need to see is the actual case statement and the sample calls of your script (w/ command line args); also, a brief description of what you mean by option `d` not working ... error message? no message? it hangs? something else?

Comment: @chepner: I did in the while statement:
`while getopts ":chapd:" option; do`
..then defined option `d`:
`
d) # Delete Screenshots
         Delete
         exit;;
`

Comment: But when you call the script, are you using `myscript -d foo` or just `myscript -d`? You haven't said *what* isn't working.

Comment: Show how you're calling the program. You haven't ruled out the observation chepner added in the very first comment, that putting a `:` after the `d` specifies that an option-argument is needed at invocation time. Certainly from your help string I don't see anything indicating that the `:` is correct/appropriate.

Comment: @chepner: ah I misunderstood... sorry. Program called like `hsshots -d`. I'm editing this to include.

Comment: If it's just `hsshots -d`, then the `:` at the end of your getopts string is wrong for the reason chepner told you in the very first comment. Take it out. It should just be `getopts :chapd option`

Comment: Hmm. [unix getopts for multiple switches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734649/unix-getopts-for-multiple-switches) is arguably a stronger duplicate. Still touches on the same `:`-only-after-a-switch-with-an-optarg problem, but it's explicitly about getopts in shell, not about the C function it's modeled from.

Comment: BTW, if you're going to replace removed code with `...`, put that `...` in a comment. We want a [mre] -- it's supposed to be minimal, yes, but it's also supposed to produce _the exact error you're asking about_ when run without changes, not a different error about a `...` command not being found.

Comment: BTW, `hsshots -d something` would have worked with your original code -- the "something" in this case becomes an optarg, an _argument to an option_, like the `:` tells getopts to expect.

Comment: @chepner: Your suggestion was correct. I didn't quite understand what you were getting at.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy's clarification drove it home. Thank you both! BTW, Charles, that link does clarify much better than the manpage. I just wanted the argument alone: `hsshots -d` rather than `hsshot -d something`. I didn't quite understand this. Thank you.